# Why are points collected with a Trimble FM 750 off by more than a mile when displayed in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gps, mapping

I have a grower that has a FM 750 and is trying to make points in a field.  When finished he takes the file out of the display and goes to his computer and he can bring up the points in the right field using Google Maps.

When he tries to lay the points in QGIS the points are more then a mile off from his field or show up in another field.  Guess what I'm looking for is a support number to get a hold of to visit about this or if the display and the QGIS systems are not compatible.

Comment: *not compatable. (sorry left that part out.)

Comment: What projection is set in QGIS? - The Trimble FM 750 looks like this http://www.trimble.com/agriculture/cfx-750.aspx  requires http://www.trimble.com/agriculture/CorrectionServices/correctionservices.aspx CenterPoint RX

Comment: ok so this is the first time dealing with this.  I am trying to get sertifide with Trimble water managment so im a green horn at this.  Where can i find the projections in the QGIS?  And what settings do you think we should be running them at.  They did get it to work with Arc GIS but had to do a lot of math to get it to work.

Comment: Where in the world are you?   Try UTM WGS84 as a setting. Also what options are there for export of data?

Comment: Along the Kansas and Nebraska Line. Are you aksing what are we tryingn to export out of the FM750?

Comment: How are you exporting the data from the TFM750, what settings are being chosen when you do that? It would seem that a kml is coming out, if it can be viewed in Google Maps. This should show up OK in QGIS. But in QGIS you would need to compare the kml to some other data. What other data is loaded in QGIS? Are you also showing a background layer of some sort in QGIS?

Comment: We are making them with the point and line set up. Then we take the AGGPS file from the FM750 and when we look at that file it gives us .shp fiels.  So we we the Vector layer to add our shape file to the map.  At the end of doing this all our county map is no where close to our points and lines.

Answer (score 4):

Also make sure the GPS receiver is set to the right UTM zone.  Probably 14N unless you're very far east along the KS/NE line.

Comment: The Grower had done this before with a diffrent set up and he said that we are supost to use the NAD83/UTM14N